# How to programatically check for lazy/eager loading

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, automated-tests

I have some hibernate queries where I expect some objects to be eargerly loaded while others are lazy-loaded.
My current approch for checking for eager loading is measuring the time it takes to access a property.

```
//Call the method i want to test.
Customer customer = loadCustomerWithProducts();

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

//Call a method on an object that sould have been eagerly loaded.
customer.getProducts().get(0).getName();

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long diff = end - start;

Assert.assertTrue(diff < 50); //Assuming that hitting the database takes longer than 50ms.
```

This aproach is very flawed, as tests will fail depending on system performance. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use

```
Hibernate.isInitialized(customer.getProducts())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Make sure the session is closed after the call to your load method, try to access the collection, and check that it doesn't throw any lazy loading exception
2. Call [`Hibernate.inInitialized(customer.getProducts())`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isInitialized%28java.lang.Object%29).